# Remove text space from a JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is a simple one for JS programmers. Base on this demo, https://codepen.io/gschier/pen/jkivt

I want 'The pen is simple.' to be 'The pen issimple.' To remove the space after 'is'.

I tried different areas with no luck. I only know CSS and HTML but not so much JS.

Of course this doesn't make sense with this demo example, I want to start it with an alphabet to make a sentence, for example

```html
<h1>A
  <span
     class="txt-rotate"
     data-period="2000"
     data-rotate='[ " great day.", "pple.", "wesome.", " shinny diamond."]'></span>
```

With the current JS result, I get "A  great day.", "A pple.", "A wesome.", "A  shinny diamond." Please advise how do I remove the extra space. Thank you.

Comment: Remove all whitespace between "A" and the start of the span in the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing space / new line after `A`

```
<h1>A<span
     class="txt-rotate"
     data-period="2000"
     data-rotate='[ " great day.", "pple.", "wesome.", " shinny diamond."]'></span>
```

**Working Demo**

https://codepen.io/aswinkumar863/pen/NWpEygj

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions, for me the easiest and most convenient is just like below.

```js
     $(document).ready(function(){
     var value=$(".txt-rotate").attr('data-rotate');
     val_array=JSON.parse(value);
     var array = val_array.map(function (el) {
    return el.trim();
        });
        array = '\'' + array.join('\',\'') + '\'';
        array="["+array+"]";
    
     $(".txt-rotate").attr('data-rotate',array);
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>A
  <span
     class="txt-rotate"
     data-period="2000"
     data-rotate='[ " great day.", "pple.", "wesome.", " shinny diamond."]'></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `replace(/  +/g, ' ')` remove multiple space